# ¿Como realizar la autenticacion de OAuth de la API de Gmail desde AWS?

Tags: python, google-api, gmail, oauth2, google-oauth

Seguí al detalle el [inicio rápido](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python?hl=es-419) de Google sobre como usar la API de Gmail de manera local. Pude realizar la autenticación OAuth sin problemas y también enviar y leer emails de mi bandeja de entrada.

Mi problema radica en que ahora deseo tener este servicio (escrito en Python) corriendo en un servicio de AWS, y me encuentro sin poder avanzar, ya que **no sé cómo hacer para realizar el proceso de OAuth desde el servicio y luego almacenar las credenciales en AWS Secrets.**

Me gustaría saber como puedo implementar esto y así poder ejecutar este servicio completamente desde AWS, habiéndome validado con mi cuenta de Google.

*Aclaro que necesito que todo el workflow sea desde AWS, no me sirve primero generar el archivo tokens.json y luego subirlo a AWS. Usar una AWS Lambda también es una opcion.*

Muchas gracias.